# Jenkins - deploy artifacts to Maven repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment

I have a basic `Springboot Maven` project and I want to be able to deploy it and make API call as it works in local.
I have a remote linux machine with `Jenkins` on it, and I am able to make a build of my application correctly. Now I want to deploy this build in the same linux machine, in a certain folder `/deploy`.
Right now I have added a *Post Build Action* on Jenkins to *Deploy artifacts to Maven repository* having the following parameters:
[image]
and right now I did not make any changes to my `pom.xml` or my maven `settings.xml`.
The error that I get is the following:

```
[INFO] Deployment in http://localhost:8080/deploy (id=test2,uniqueVersion=true)
Deploying the main artifact reag.login-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Downloading: http://localhost:8080/deploy/reag/login/reag.login/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
ERROR: Failed to retrieve remote metadata reag.login:reag.login:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata reag.login:reag.login:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to deploymentRepo (http://localhost:8080/deploy): Access denied to: http://localhost:8080/deploy/reag/login/reag.login/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata reag.login:reag.login:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata reag.login:reag.login:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to deploymentRepo (http://localhost:8080/deploy): Access denied to: http://localhost:8080/deploy/reag/login/reag.login/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
```

The machine where I'm working is protected by username and password, I tried to put them in the `settings.xml` file but nothing changes. Does anyone know which are the steps to make this process work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is here: `Access denied to: http://localhost:8080/deploy/reag/login/reag.login/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.`...check if your credential data is correct...

Comment: BTW: Why not using Maven for doing this job?

Answer (score 0):

Local artifact deployment is done by `mvn clean install`.
The `install` goal copies your artifact into your local maven repository (Default [USER_HOME]/.m2/repository).

If you want to deploy your artifact to another service, like a [Nexus Maven Repository](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), then you need to deploy and also provide the credentials for that machine in your `settings.xml`, or even better setup a private/public key authentication for the machines.

I think Jenkins is trying to do the remote deploy, which is only working if you run a Maven Repository on your machine (like the Nexus)

Answer (score 0):

"deploy" in Maven parlance means "upload the built artifacts and their metadata (such as pom files) to a repository manager.

It does *not* mean "copy the artifact to any location that you want".

Therefore as @funfried mentioned, you need to actually have a repository manager running.

If that is the case then the following is how you set up the maven configuration.

Maven links credentials to servers via the `id` element.

Your settings.xml file would have your credentials setup something like:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>newhope-nexus</id>
        <username>steve</username>
        <password>{1T7Jmp/PBoQH4cvFjZDTaDe/F/Z+D9rJ925rf+3H1LY=}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

And then your project model (project pom or parent pom) should define it's `distributionManagement`:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>newhope-nexus</id>
        <url>http://newhope:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>newhope-nexus</id>
        <url>http://newhope:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Note that the ids all match.

The `mvn deploy` from Jenkins should then work correctly.